# How do I add a new library to android dependencies using eclipse adt?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-fragments, android-library

I am trying to add external library to android dependancies using eclipse adt. I have a couple of libraries like pull to refresh etc in there. But everytime I add a new library jar file it shows outside of the android dependancies library folder. How do I make it such that it is coupled with the other libraries as a part of android dependancies library. Here's what I did so far:
 Project> Properties> java build path > libraries> add jars ( also tried adding external jars), but it always showed my new jar file independantly, i want it to be a part of android dependancies). any clue?
Here's a screen shot, I would like to add it as a part of android dependencies:

[image]

Comment: Can you describe why you want this? Usually adding the jar(s) to the libs folder is enough, from then on you have access to the jar in the code of your project.

Comment: I added a screenshot. I would like to add it as a part of android dependencies, as in inside it with other libraries I have in there like pulltorefresh/library etc.

Comment: got it thanks, seems to be working, can you post this as an answer so i can give you +25

Comment: No problem :) just posted it as answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I still do not get why that is important to you.

However, when you reference a library project: rightclick project->properties->Android->Add then the jar goes into Android Dependencies.

If you add the jar directly to your project under libs or using build path, then it goes under Android Private Libraries.

Both methods works but referencing a library project can have benefits if you want to alter the code of the library during development.

Comment: Unless AAR is supported, Referencing a library project is also the only way if `res` is included in the export.

Comment: You did not answer the question. I have the Sample project that has the 'sherlock action bar' library in the dependancies and it compiles and runs OK and I have my project which does not have it and it does not work so for me it is important to know how to add a jar to the Android Dependancies so that the project properties would look the same for both projects

Comment: I have managed to add the jar to the Android Dependancies by manually editing project.properties file

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had the following in my project.properties file

```
target=android-18
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
android.library=false
android.library.reference.1=..\\com_facebook_android

android.library.reference.2=../actionbarsherlock
```

After I changed the last line to

```
android.library.reference.2=..\\actionbarsherlock
```

actionbarsherlock.jar appeared in the Android Dependancies and I could run my app without the java.lang.noclassdeffounderror exception

Comment: The question is about dependencies being added as either a private library or android dependency. This is an example of a local configuration problem in your setup and has nothing to do with the question.