# What is wrong with my Map Activity based simple Android app?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm new to android development but am still learning and have created a few apps of simple activities. But this app which needs me to have a google map service activity can't be executed by me. Please review the codes and explain any error. I'd be very thankful to you.

Here's the Manifest code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<permission
  android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
  android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="in.csbuddy.aaas.Aaas"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="AIzaSyAJJlKWPyQmwjfua1HV0fVHVkbN4Ny_iaw" />
</application>
```

And the java code

```
package in.csbuddy.aaas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Aaas extends Activity {
  static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
  static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
  private GoogleMap map;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_aaas);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
        .title("Hamburg"));
    Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(KIEL)
        .title("Kiel")
        .snippet("Kiel is cool")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.aaas, menu);
    return true;
  }

}
```

and the layout file is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LOGCAT:

```
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4745)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:271)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at in.csbuddy.aaas.Aaas.onCreate(Aaas.java:23)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
04-11 00:26:32.997: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 00:26:32.997: W/ActivityManager(842):   Force finishing activity in.csbuddy.aaas/.Aaas
```

Everytime I try to run, the app won't open and show the "Unfortunately.." error. Please help me.

Comment: If your app is crashing then please post the logcat as well. Otherwise, mention the complete error.

Comment: @SaumikBhattacharya 
Logcat added. Kindly review.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following in your manifest file.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Also in your `build.gradle` for app, you need to add the following dependencies.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
```

Also you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372391/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable) for additional help!

Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: I am using Eclipse adt. Not sure about your build.gradle part.

Comment: I use Android Studio for building android apps, so not sure about Eclipse ADT configuration. However, you can refer [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355971/how-do-i-add-a-new-library-to-android-dependencies-using-eclipse-adt) to add dependencies using Eclipse ADT.